# Bookmarklets manager to replace Blummy.com

Tags: javascript, synchronization, bookmark

For years now I've been using the freeware blummy.com to manage by links and bookmarklets, until it was instantly shut down yesterday with this message:

> blummy **was** a tool for quick access to your favorite web services via your bookmark toolbar. As of November 2020 it has been **retired**.
>
> <sup>- blummy.com</sup>

While it existed ([since at least 2005 according to archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20051101005419/http://www.blummy.com/), it was basically a cross-browser bookmarklet that runs other links and/or bookmarklets, so you could manage and put everything in a single Favorite/Bookmark item, plus some extra features on the way.

Being cloud based you could share it with your family and peers and then manage it remotely.

No matter which website you were at, every time you clicked on this Favorite/Bookmark item, it immediately loaded all your available items:

[image: A sample Blummy]

It's noteworthy to mention some accounts were preserved in read-only mode, some of which are mine after the owner personally agreed to preserve them.
But I assume it's only a matter of time before even the read-only accounts will be deleted.

So now it's gone, is there anything else like it? Keep in mind there are bookmark managers out there, but I'm looking at the very least for:

1. Support for bookmarklets, not just regular links
2. Cloud based - no installation, remote management, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some convincing, the site became alive again. Let's hope it stays this way.